# x11vnc fails with "buffer overflow detected" on CentOs 7.2

Tags: vnc-server

On the client connection x11vnc fails with "buffer overflow" error.

```
*** buffer overflow detected ***: x11vnc terminated
======= Backtrace: =========
/usr/lib64/libc.so.6(__fortify_fail+0x37)[0x7fc9281ff597]
/usr/lib64/libc.so.6(+0x10c750)[0x7fc9281fd750]
/usr/lib64/libc.so.6(+0x10e507)[0x7fc9281ff507]
/usr/lib64/libvncserver.so.0(rfbProcessNewConnection+0x114)[0x7fc92ac19764]
/usr/lib64/libvncserver.so.0(rfbCheckFds+0x3f8)[0x7fc92ac19c98]
/usr/lib64/libvncserver.so.0(rfbProcessEvents+0x1d)[0x7fc92ac10c3d]
x11vnc[0x4a0951]
x11vnc[0x463d9e]
x11vnc[0x410c0a]
/usr/lib64/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf5)[0x7fc928112b15]
x11vnc[0x41b201]
======= Memory map: ========
00400000-00542000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 164900702                          /usr/bin/x11vnc
00741000-00742000 r--p 00141000 fd:00 164900702                          /usr/bin/x11vnc
00742000-00788000 rw-p 00142000 fd:00 164900702                          /usr/bin/x11vnc
00788000-009ca000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
015fa000-016f9000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
```

I'm using x11vnc-0.9.13-11.el7.x86_64 on CentOs 7.2.

Comment: It could be nice to have a x11vnc tag since the server quite specific.

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been already reported [on Ubuntu](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/x11vnc/+bug/1175098)  and [on Fedora](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=972618).

It is due to a [known bug on old versions of libvncserver](https://sourceforge.net/p/libvncserver/mailman/message/35129113/).

In my case, the bug was due to libvncserver-0.9.9-9 and solved by updating to a newer version libvncserver-0.9.9-13 (apparently it was solved somewhere after 0.9.9-10).

```
sudo yum update libvncserver
```